# onClick event change class name react js

Tags: reactjs, events, onclick, classname

I'm trying to change the color of an element created from a map loop.
How can I change just one of them by clicking on it?
And how can I leave the colors as they are when I logged in and out of the component?

I tried to use hooks but once you click on the element, every element created comes in green instead of red.

The elements should be red and change from red to green by clicking. Each new element created should be red.

pls help[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpIn5.png)

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Bulb} from '@styled-icons/ionicons-outline/Bulb'
import {HotTub} from '@styled-icons/material-twotone/HotTub'
import {Radio} from '@styled-icons/zondicons/Radio'
import {Fan} from '@styled-icons/fa-solid/Fan'

export default function Rooms(props) {

    const [flag, setFlag] = useState('off')
    
    const newArr = props.arr[props.index].appliances
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([props.arr[props.index].appliances])
    const [disply, setDisply] = useState('none')
    const [applist, setAppList] = useState()

    let disFunc = () => {
        if(disply === 'none') {
            setDisply('block')
        } else {
            setDisply('none')
        }
    }

    let colorApp = (item, index) => {
       setIconStyle()
    }
    
    let appliances = (e) => {
        let eventValue = e.target.value

        if(eventValue === '<Fan/>' ) {
            setAppList([<Fan/>])
        } else if(eventValue === '<HotTub/>') {
            setAppList([<HotTub/>])
        }
        else if(eventValue === '<Radio/>') {
            setAppList([<Radio/>])
        }
        else if(eventValue === '<Bulb/>') {
            setAppList([<Bulb/>])
        }       
    }

    let newAppliances = () => {
        props.funcApp(applist, props.index)
    }

    let chengefalg = () => {
        props.colorFunc(1)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Smart House</h1>
            
            <Link to='/'><p>{props.index}</p></Link>
            <p>Room type: {props.type}</p>
            <p>Room name: {props.name}</p>
            <button onClick={disFunc}>Add appliances</button><br/><br/><br/>

            <div style={{display: disply}}>
                <select onChange={appliances}>
                    <option selected value="4">Add</option>
                    <option value={'<Fan/>'}>Air-Conditioner</option>
                    <option value={'<HotTub/>'}>boilermaker</option>
                    <option value={'<Radio/>'}>stereo system</option>
                    <option value={'<Bulb/>'}>lamp</option>
                </select>
                <button onClick={newAppliances}>Add</button>
            </div>

            {newArr.map((item,index) => (
                <p className={flag} onClick={() => {
                    setFlag('on')
                }}>{item}</p>
            )) }
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give each flag a unique id

```
id = {`flag-${index}`}
```

then pass the index as an argument in the onClick function.

```
onClick={ ()=> toggleFlag(index) }
```

then add the function to update the class for this flag only:

```
toggleFlag = (index) => {
  document.getElementById(`flag-${index}`).classList.toggle('on');
}
```

you can also use css to gradually change the color.

```
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;  
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;  
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;  
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;  
  transition: all 1s ease;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
It's half working
When I return to the same room to which I added appliances they are not kept as green as they were before

Answer (score 0):

You could also make another component for the p - tag and use useState in there

```
   ... 
       {newArr.map((item, index) => (
            <PTag item={item}></PTag>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }


    const PTag = ({ item }) => {
      const [flag, setFlag] = useState('not_on');
      return (
        <p
          className={flag}
          onClick={() => {
            setFlag(flag == 'not_on' ? 'on' : 'not_on');
          }}
        >
          {item}
        </p>
      );
    };
```

Comment: It gives me an error
React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback.

Comment: yea, I have edited it now. I had tested it with Next.js a React framework. There it worked.